# Are questions about firewalls on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is the intent of this site to stick to a core Unix functionality and not go into topics like firewalls? It seems like there is some cross-over with serverfault.com when you start getting into some topics.

Answer (score 6):

This site technically has 100% crossover with [SU](http://superuser.com) (it's a subset of the questions allowed there), so I wouldn't worry about potential SF crossover.

What exactly do you mean by "topics like firewalls"? A question like this I would definitely consider on-topic here:

> How do I write an iptables rule to do X

Comment: Should have been clearer. I was thinking along the lines of @xenoterracide when you have networking questions which go beyond syntax.

Comment: I don't agree it has 100% crossover with SU. I think it also has crossover with SF. SU and SF themselves have some crossover. If I have a Unix-ish question, I'm often not sure if I should ask it on SU or SF. But if it's a Unix-ish question, I know it will be adequate here. And according to some of the SE coordinators, [Crossover isn't necessarily a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5837/how-to-handle-overlapping-subjects/5839#5839).

Comment: @Stefan:  Writing shell or Perl scripts for system administration could easily belong here or on Stack Overflow or both.  There's a lot of overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Um... depends obviously it should be related to a firewall on a unix/linux system (PF and iptables comes to mind. no cisco questions) I'd think it should be more syntax than anything. Though personally I think the Network guys deserve there own Q&A site like [this area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7833/network-security?referrer=LemKZjYi1nRpdZnri3IIJQ2). Because networking isn't really Servers. IMO SF and SU are TOO general.

Comment: SU used to be even [more broad](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/) than it is now; it was essentially a free-for-all place to shove all the non-programming questions that kept getting posted to SO

Answer (score 1):

My feeling would be that questions specifically relating to Linux and Unix systems would be on topic, so I'd be comfortable with questions on configuring Unix/Linux systems.  Once the questions leave the box, I'd consider them off-topic.